# Fairytale about two rival fairies who made a bet

Tags: story-identification

There were two rival fairies who made a bet about something. The first fairy raised a prince to be unable to decide even the simplest thing and the second fairy raised a princess.

When the prince and the princess grew up, the prince was introduced to twelve princesses, each with unique personalities i.e., one was kind, one was beautiful, one was good at singing. Of course, he couldn’t decide which to marry.

It turned out that the twelve princesses were in fact one princess and hence, the second fairy won the bet since she cured the prince’s indecisiveness.

Comment: It might be a memory from multiple stories.

The twelve princesses idea might come from the **"The Twelve Dancing Princesses"** collected by the Brothers Grimm. This story is very similar to the story of Cinderella 

And the prince, who can't decide whom to marry, might be from **"The Prince and the Three Golden Hairs"** by the Brothers Grimm. The story is about a prince who is unable to decide whom to marry between three princesses, each of whom possesses one of three golden hairs.  

I'm unsure about a fairy tale of fairies raising a prince and princess and making bets.

Comment: Was this a book? Short story? Picture book? Other?